# SQL use column values for IF conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have a Conditions table that looks like this :

`Conditions`

- ConditionID
- MappingID
- VariableID
- CompareToVariableID
- ConditionOperator ( can be == or <> )
- ConjunctionOperator ( can be && or || )
- ConjunctionOrder

Now I have a SP that I want to implement these conditions on depending on MappingID.

If a MappingID is selected, all mapped conditions should be checked before anything happens in my SP.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Conditions
WHERE MappingID = @MappingID
ORDER BY ConjunctionOrder
```

For example if a certain `MappingID` had three rows in the `Conditions` table then :

```
IF VARIABLEID CONDITIONOPERATOR COMPARETOVARIABLEID CONJUNCTIONOPERATOR --row1
VARIABLEID CONDITIONOPERATOR COMPARETOVARIABLEID CONJUNCTIONOPERATOR  --row2
VARIABLEID CONDITIONOPERATOR COMPARETOVARIABLEID --row3 (ignore ConjunctionOperator for last row)
BEGIN
   --my code goes here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   --my code here
END
```

I would like to know how I can implement the IF statement.

Comment: SQL doesn't have a lot of facilities for meta-programming like this. If you can solve it somewhere outside of SQL Server, I'd usually recommend doing so. I'd usually also recommend a better representation - your current representation can express one of the following, but not both, so far as I can see: `(((A && B) || C) && D)`, `((A && B) || (C && D))` (which one you get depends on whether you interpret the conjunction operators left-to-right, or using precedence). (`A && (B || C) && D)` would also be possible)

Comment: I had the same thoughts when I first saw this. I was told this is for an admin panel and it is supposed to work this way though. After all all boolean expressions with parentheses can also be expressed without parentheses.

Comment: I answered your question, but another one came to my mind. Where do you get your variables from?

Comment: @ShyJ You didn't really answered his question, you mostly posted a comment

Comment: @ShyJ they're stored in the DB table `Conditions`. They're input from the Admin Panel.

Comment: @hermann Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I wanted to ask where are the variable _values_ stored?

Comment: @ShyJ Oops. They're stored in another table called `Variables`.

Comment: I would argue that it should be easier for someone(say an administrator) to learn how to write sql select statements than to use the "Admin Panel".

Comment: Why are you only allowed to use `'=='` and `'<>'`?  Are only comparing boolean values?  Otherwise, you've extremely limited the kinds of searches you can do.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the rest are future implementations

Comment: @hermann - whilst it's true that you should be able to recompose any boolean expression with arbitrary parenthesis, any of decent complexity will lead to a lot of repetition, and your current structures don't help clean it up. Decomposing logic into conjunctive or disjunctive normal form (or a stack-based evaluation form) might help. But using an *actual* programming language to express the logic would be far better. Structures such as the one you've shown tend to come about from building "flexible" systems (that turn out to need programmers to deal with anyway - they're not actually simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is like this (these are the steps in your stored procedure)

1. Take your conditions off the `Conditons` table and produce a special booolean expression out of it. You can do it by using a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) over your `SELECT` query from your post. You should convert your variable IDs so that they won't mix with the variable values (you'll see later what I mean). Let's suppose your query returned:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|VariableID |COmpareToVariableID |ConditionOperator |ConjunctionOperator |ConjunctionOrder|
|-----------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|----------------|
|A          |B                   |==                |&&                  |1               |
|C          |D                   |>> (NE)           |                    |2               |
|-----------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|----------------|
```

Your expression (kept in a local SP variable) should be:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE #A# = #B# AND #C# >> #D#
```

In other words you add `SELECT 1 WHERE` at the beginning and relpace condition operator `==` with `=` and conjunction operator `&&` with 'AND', and `||` with 'OR'

1. Now you do a cursor query over your `Variables` table. In each loop you [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) the names of the variables with its values (i.e. #A# is replaced with A value). At the end your expression should look like 'SELECT 1 WHERE 1=2 AND 3<>3'.
2. You use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute your dynamically created query. You can put the output in an OUTPUT parameter and check it in your `IF` statment in your SP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of what you want:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = '{0}') Select 1 ELSE SELECT 0
```

You can also try:

```
IF (SELECT ConditionID FROM Conditions)=COMPARETOVARIABLEID 
BEGIN
---Do your thing
END
GO
```